# What is the proper Gradle setup for a Kotlin Project to compile to MacOSX?

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin

I am having difficulty combing through the Kotlinlang and Gradle documentation. There seems to be a confusing mix of examples on how to make a native compiling kotlin project. I was looking at this tutorial:

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/native/gradle-for-kotlin-native.html

but it seems to be wildly different from this other gradle setup:

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/using-gradle.html#configuring-dependencies

I generated a new `Kotlin-native-common` project in Intellij and the resulting auto-generated build script looks like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'kotlin-platform-common' version '1.2.71'
}

version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common"
    testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-annotations-common"
    testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-common"
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

The above build-script doesn't look like the examples given in the above tutorials. What exactly should this build-script look like to compile to MacOSX native and why does the tutorial example show using `konan` for native compiling while the auto-generated script does not?

Thanks

Comment: What you've generated is a multiplatform library. To generate a Kotlin/Native project, use Kotlin 1.3 RC and select Kotlin/Native as the project type.

Comment: So the current Kotlin 1.2.71 doesn't support native compiling? I select `Create new Project -> Kotlin -> Kotlin (Multiplatform-Experimental)`

Comment: No, it doesn't. Before 1.3, Kotlin/Native is a separate release with a separate plugin, only supporting CLion and AppCode.

Comment: Understood. Well, I am excited for 1.3 then!